# How to change the distance format of mapbox navigation SDK from imperial to metric in android apps?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, mapbox

I have the app that uses map by Mapbox API and needs to navigate the trip of the user, so I need to show the distance format in metric.
However, it defined as imperial by default in navigation SDK. To get more understanding see the following pics.

[The pic 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zHRBb.png), it shows the distance format in imperial as default.

[The pic 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oLKb7.png), it shows the distance format in metric.

To change the default format, see the below codes that I used in my app:

- In Java

```
NavigationRoute.builder(v.getContext())
.accessToken(accessToken)
.origin(originPosition)
.destination(destinationPosition)
.voiceUnits(DirectionsCriteria.METRIC) //add this to change the format
.build().getRoute(new Callback<DirectionsResponse>(){
                            ...});
```

- In Kotlin

```
NavigationRoute.builder(context)
.accessToken(accessToken)
.origin(originPosition)
.destination(destinationPosition)
.voiceUnits(DirectionsCriteria.METRIC) //add this to change the format
.build().getRoute(object : Callback<DirectionsResponse>(){
                            ...});
```

For more information about the navigation SDK, visit the documentation page [enter link here](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/overview/) and the used version is *v0.42.6*.

Enjoy your life.

Comment: Where do you see a problem with this behaviour?

Comment: I thought that a problem as required for the app when I was working on it, but I get the solution after seeking in this behavior. So, I shared here to help others